# Rails 3: How to "redirect_to" in Ajax call?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, redirect

The following `attempt_login` method is called using Ajax after a login form is submitted.

```
class AccessController < ApplicationController
  [...]
  def attempt_login
    authorized_user = User.authenticate(params[:username], params[:password])

    if authorized_user
      session[:user_id] = authorized_user.id
      session[:username] = authorized_user.username
      flash[:notice] = "Hello #{authorized_user.name}."
      redirect_to(:controller => 'jobs', :action => 'index')
    else
      [...]
    end
  end
end
```

The problem is that `redirect_to` doesn't work.

How would you solve this ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Finally, I just replaced

```
redirect_to(:controller => 'jobs', :action => 'index')
```

with this:

```
render :js => "window.location = '/jobs/index'"
```

and it works fine!

Comment: finally, this only renders the view and ignores the controller code that redirect_to would execute.

Comment: This seems the best - would be nice to add a flash message in there also, but pretty nice.

Comment: @mackmack - What do you mean? What controller code is getting ignored?

Comment: wouldnt this require an `eval` call on the client?

Comment: A better approach would be `render :js => "window.location = '#{jobs_path}'"`

Comment: It works, but wouldn't it be a lot better to pass back the redirect location with an actual json success message and do the redirecting on the front end?

Comment: Isn't `jobs_path` basically as rigid as the URL? If the URL changes, so would the name of the route, unless you are being extra careful. Another alternative would be `render js: "window.location = '#{polymorphic_path(@job.class)}'"` and use the calculated resourceful route based on the Job model. This only works if your routes are resourceful and use standard naming conventions that line up with your models. (Or if you specify model_name on your models so that they generate the right route names.)

Comment: Awesome. Anyone has any idea why the the simple redirect_to does not work?

Comment: @Tasos Anesiadis, redirect_to doesn't work when the form is a 'remote' Rails form  because the browser's been told to interpret the response from the controller as Javascript. You can see the redirect_to page in the Response tab (via the Network panel) of Chrome DevTools but what's needed instead is an instruction to the browser from the controller to go find a different page. The window.location solutions provided here, or changing the form to a regular 'local' form are required, unless you want to get into manually submitting and processing the form data via fetch() and JSON.

Answer (score 71):

There is very easy way to keep the flash for the next request. In your controller do something like

```
flash[:notice] = 'Your work was awesome! A unicorn is born!'
flash.keep(:notice)
render js: "window.location = '#{root_path}'"
```

The `flash.keep` will make sure the flash is kept for the next request.
So when the `root_path` is rendered, it will show the given flash message. Rails is awesome :)

Answer (score 28):

I think this is slightly nicer:

`render js: "window.location.pathname='#{jobs_path}'"`

Comment: slightly slightly nicer: `render js: "window.location.pathname = #{jobs_path.to_json}"`

Answer (score 27):

In one of my apps, i use JSON to carry on the redirect and flash message data. It would look something like this:

```
class AccessController < ApplicationController
  ...
  def attempt_login
    ...
    if authorized_user
      if request.xhr?
        render :json => {
          :location => url_for(:controller => 'jobs', :action => 'index'),
          :flash => {:notice => "Hello #{authorized_user.name}."}
        }
      else
        redirect_to(:controller => 'jobs', :action => 'index')
      end
    else
      # Render login screen with 422 error code
      render :login, :status => :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
end
```

And simple jQuery example would be:

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  type: 'json',
  success: functon(data) {
    data = $.parseJSON(data);
    if (data.location) {
      window.location.href = data.location;
    }
    if (data.flash && data.flash.notice) {
      // Maybe display flash message, etc.
    }
  },
  error: function() {
    // If login fails, sending 422 error code sends you here.
  }
})
```

Comment: Lots of good information here. Good and proper use of the render :location, of the :status option, and the xhr? check. As more web applications adopt APIs to serve mobile apps and the such, I hope to see things in this post become more standardized. Definitely have my upvote. Great Answer

Answer (score 20):

**Combining the best of all answers:**

```
...
if request.xhr?
  flash[:notice] = "Hello #{authorized_user.name}."
  flash.keep(:notice) # Keep flash notice around for the redirect.
  render :js => "window.location = #{jobs_path.to_json}"
else
...
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I used it. However, now for the testing, when I try to request this action as JS, it raises a CORS warning : ActionController::InvalidCrossOriginRequest. Do you have any idea of how to integrate this in tests ?

Answer (score 0):

```
def redirect_to(options = {}, response_status = {})
  super(options, response_status)
  if request.xhr?
    # empty to prevent render duplication exception
    self.status = nil
    self.response_body = nil
    path = location
    self.location = nil

    render :js => "window.location = #{path.to_json}"
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't want to modify my controller actions so I came up with this hack:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def redirect_to options = {}, response_status = {}
    super

    if request.xhr?
      self.status        = 200
      self.response_body = "<html><body><script>window.location.replace('#{location}')</script></body></html>"
    end
  end
end
```