# Rails 3: "redirect_to" doesn't work well after Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 application user adds a new message to forum using Ajax:

```
<%= form_tag("/forum/add_new_message", :remote => true) do %>
  <%= text_area_tag("new_message_area") %>
<% end %>
```

Here is my controller's code:

```
def index
  @messages = Message.all
end

def add_new_message
  Message.create(:text => params[:new_message_area], ...)                 
  redirect_to(:action => 'index')
end
```

The problem is that after user adds a new message, `redirect_to(:action => 'index')` executed, but the page is not refreshed, i.e. I don't see the new message.

Why ?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call/18443966

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The web browser is expecting some javascript to be executed after the ajax has been called. Your code should work when javascript is disabled in the browser.

In the add_new_message method you should add:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(:action => 'index') }
  format.js
end
```

Then some javascript in add_new_message.js.erb will be executed, so to redirect to the index, the code in add_new_message.js.erb should look like:

```
window.location = '<%= forums_path %>'; //or whatever other path
```

Although both the HTML and javascript do the same thing. Why is the ajax needed in the first place?

Comment: But then how to you render error and notice messages on the redirected_to page?

Comment: @EricSteen Use the flash hash, e.g. `flash[:error] = "Oh no!"` and then in the controller action or view that is being redirected to you can access the message, e.g. `The error was: <%= flash[:error] %>`

Answer (score 2):

I'd be tempted to go for something like this in the controller:

```
def index
  @messages = Message.all
end

def add_new_message
  Message.create(:text => params[:new_message_area], ...)                 
  render js: %(window.location.pathname='#{messages_path}')
end
```