# Rails redirect_to Parent Partial / View

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial

So I'm trying to redirect to my root_url, but from several partials deep. The redirect works but it only redirects within the partial. It worked fine before implementing partials. To redirect I have a before_filter that checks the session and redirects to root_url if the session is no longer valid.

Another note: I am making ajax calls to return other partials (like loading divs created server side) and it seems like after the session expires instead of returning the partial's html it returns the login html its supposed to redirect to. This is so annoying.

So
**application.html.erb**

```
<div id="main-contain" class="container">
    <%= yield %>
</div>
```

renders
**_content.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: 'partials/content' %>
```

which renders
**_my_partial.html.erb**

```
<%= render partial: 'partials/my_partial' %>
```

and when the session ends the redirect only works within the deepest partial.

Any ideas? I've searched up and down after scratching my head for too long.

Edit:

Here is the before filter function

```
unless is_authorized

      flash[:content] = { title: 'Login Required', message: 'You must log in to access dash.'  } 
      redirect_to '/gate'  

end
```

where 'gate' is my login page. This is the route:

```
match 'gate' => 'gate#latch'
```

Comment: Can you show the code doing the redirect?

Comment: Where is that filter function?  It seems like it should be part of a controller rather than in a partial.

Comment: @aelfric5578 its in a helper module.

Comment: Can you show where it's called from?  Without further context I can't think of why you need to redirect from inside of a partial in the first place.

Comment: I'm redirecting from the before_filter, rather than the partial, which is in the application controller so it is inherited by all controllers.

Comment: Sorry to pile on even more questions, but what do you mean by the redirect only works within the deepest partial? Any action when called after the session has expired should trigger the filter to redirect.

Comment: no worries. So yeah it does redirect fine, but loads the url only within the partial. So any of the outer partials remain the same. Its supposed to redirect to my login page, which right when this happens looks like it gets rendered into a div.

Comment: What event triggers the `before_filter`?

Comment: any controller action, its in the application controller

Comment: Are you making an ajax call? It could be that the response handler for your ajax call is loading the response into a div inside the partial, and so you don't see the whole page redirecting. Maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out :) after much head scratching. I could only seem to return the login page as html rather than redirecting. My solution:

**in my authentication check:**

```
unless is_authorized

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to '/gate' }
    format.js { render :json => { redirect: true } , :status => :unauthorized }
  end

end # is_authorized
```

**and some javascript:**

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    statusCode: {
      401: function(data) {
        var response = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        if (response.redirect == true) {
          location.href = "/gate";
        }
      }
    }
  });
```

So all I really needed to do was send a 401 back when the session is expired, listen for 401s in AJAX calls, and finally redirect if we recieve a 401 and redirect parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ajax calls, you should return a JS redirecting/reloading page; otherwise page won't go to the '/gate' URL