# Why using format.html {redirect_to @user} does not redirect to the page I want

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

when using jquery ajax in rails, I want to redirect_to /users/:id (i.e., users#show) after a ajax request, but I failed. Following is the related code:

app/views/users/new_skills.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@user, url: "create_skills", html: { id: "create_skills_form" }) do |f| %>
  .....
  <%= f.submit "Save", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
<% end %>
```

app/assets/javascript/users.js

```
jQuery.fn.submitWithAjax = function() {
  $(this).submit(function(event) {
    ......
    var url = $(this).attr("action");
    $.post(url, {skills: skill_array}, null, "script");
    return false;
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#create_skills_form").submitWithAjax();
});
```

app/controllers/users_controller.rb

```
  def create_skills
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    ......

    flash[:notice] = "Thank you! You have successfully add new skills!"
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to @user }
      format.js
    end
  end
```

after users_controller return, the log in the server is as follows:

```
Started POST "/users/1/create_skills" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-23 15:26:24 +0800
Processing by UsersController#create_skills as JS
  Parameters: {"skills"=>["skill_1__Primary"], "id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Skill Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "skills".* FROM "skills" INNER JOIN "abilities" ON "skills"."id" = "abilities"."skill_id" WHERE "abilities"."user_id" = ?  [["user_id", 1]]
  Rendered users/create_skills.js.erb (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 6ms (Views: 1.9ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)
```

what I want is just redirect to the user/:id page after the ajax request, which is route to users#show, just as what I write in the users_controller.rb:

```
        respond_to do |format|
          format.html { redirect_to @user }
          format.js
        end
```

but after the ajax request, the page does not do anything, just remains what it is before the request.

Can anybody tell me why? is there something wrong with my code?

Please help me, I'm just a newbee in RoR, there may be some just stupid errors.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you should add remote:true to the form?

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, It's to do with how a web browser treats the response. As the request was made using Ajax, it is not going to follow the same procedure as if it had been initiated by a hyperlink.

Solution, in your Ajax, deal with the successful response and add:

```
window.location.href = "redirect location"
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this line in your console:

> Processing by UsersController#create_skills as JS

This means the request is handled with your format.js block in your respond_to block where you do not have a redirect. Actually the redirect will not work even if you put it there too.

See the following answer on how to redirect in an ajax call:
[Rails 3: How to "redirect_to" in Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call)
(It is similar to what veritas1 replied)

Btw, it seems you also have a create_skills.js.erb file. You can put the redirect there too:

```
window.location.href = "<%= user_path(@user) %>"
```

Comment: Thank you, that work for me. However currently I just write the js code in the controller: format.js { render js: "window.location.href='#{user_path(@user)}'" }. but I still not know how to dynamically set the window.location.href in the create_skills.js.erb file. do you have any idea?

Comment: The last paragraph of my reply basically tells you how to redirect from the create_skils.js.erb you just need copy paste it. I edited my answer to fit your need better.