# Rails redirect_to after jquery $.post

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

Why won't my browser go to the new page when I submit?

In my view I have a button that posts data to and action in my controller.

**my coffee script:**

```
$.post "/token/create", json
```

**TokenController#create**

```
redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Parser was successfully created.'
```

The **log file** looks like it works:

```
Started POST "/token/create" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-08 10:27:39 -0400
Processing by TokenController#create as */*
...
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 37ms (ActiveRecord: 10.0ms)


Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-08 10:27:40 -0400
Processing by VisitorsController#index as */*
...
Completed 200 OK in 2891ms (Views: 2886.6ms | ActiveRecord: 3.0ms)
```

But the page I am on is not changing. How do I make the page go to whatever page I specify in the "redirect_to" line?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call "Rails 3: How to “redirect_to” in Ajax call?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do like the following:

```
def create
  # do some stuff
  if request.xhr? # test if the request is an AJAX call
    render js: "document.location = '#{root_path}'"
  else
    redirect_to root_path, notice: 'Parser was successfully created.' 
  end
end
```

You want to use `flash` also in the AJAX cases? check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18443966/976775 (and be nice, vote up his answer if it helps you)

Comment: Is there a way to pass my "notice" in with 'render js:'?

Comment: Ahah I just updated my answer like 2 seconds right after you posted the comment @Jeff

Comment: Thanks this is exactly it. Upvoted the other question and answer too.

Comment: If your application is using both AJAX and regular HTTP request, I can show you a way to implement a helper in order to avoid writing this condition on the redirect. Let me know if you need it @Jeff

Answer (score 0):

Because you are performing an ajax call.
You have to change the document.location via javascript as a response

create.js.erb

```
document.location = <%= root_url.inspect %>
```

for instance