# redirect_to after rescue_from is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to catch a custom error, and redirect to root path after it occurs. My code in controller looks like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  rescue_from Errors::MyError, :with => :my_error

  private

  def my_error
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "my Error"
  end
end
```

Redirect is not working, after error occurs I am still at the same page. What is funny, my server logs shows that I was redirected.

```
Redirected to http.....
Completed 302 Found in 1908ms (ActiveRecord: 0.5ms)
```

What happened? And why redirect havent occur?

Comment: did your error happen when you were doing an AJAX call?

Comment: Yes I am and I think thats the problem

Answer (score 1):

When you are doing an AJAX call to your server, the browser expect the response to be in javascript ( you talk to me in the JS language, I answer using JS language too, quite simple ). In your case, you need to test if the request is HTML or Javascript, and use the corresponding redirect:

```
def my_error
  path_to_redirect = root_path

  if request.xhr? # tests if the request comes from an AJAX call
    render :js => "window.location = '#{path_to_redirect}'"
  else
    redirect_to path_to_redirect, alert: "my Error"
  end
end
```

---

For more answers about AJAX redirects in Rails: [Rails 3: How to "redirect_to" in Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call)