# Display Ajax ResponseText in alert Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The reason I am asking this question is because I am not 100% sure of what I should be looking to do in terms of implementation, googling has probably made me a little unclearer so hoping someone can explain.

I have an "Add to Cart" button that fires an XHR request to a controller action, but this controller has a before_filter `authenticate_user!`

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def add
    $redis.sadd current_user_cart, params[:image_id]
    render json: current_user.cart_count, status: 200
  end
end
```

To handle the redirect upon a `401` i have this piece of CoffeeScript

```
$(document).on "ajaxError", (event, request, settings) ->
  if request.status == 401
  window.location.href = '/users/login'
```

At this point `request.responseText` == `You need to sign in or sign up before continuing.`

The page then redirects to `/users/login` and i would like to show this message as i would any other other Flash message

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <div class="dima-alert fade-in dima-alert-<%= key.to_s == 'notice' ? 'success' : 'error' %>" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= value if value.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

How would i get the message to persist through with the redirect and show on my page

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, add the response message as an argument on the login URL:

```
window.location.href = '/users/login?msg=' + encodeURIComponent(response);
```

Then in ruby grab the message from the URL parameters and add it to your `flash` hash:

```
flash["response-msg"] = params[:msg]
```

...after which it will get displayed in the `flash.each` loop you have.

Comment: whilst I appreciate your answer, I'm not really sure I want the message in the url, I'm thinking there must be a more `Ruby` way.. I'll keep looking thanks , ive come across this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call which i think touches on what i need to do

Comment: OK, I understand, but then remove the javascript, jquery and ajax tags and code, as you are attracting answers based on those technologies, while you really want a ruby-sided answer, where the client does not receive the 401 response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't work with ruby+device, but did you try a GET-Variable

```
window.location.href = '/users/login?message=yourMessageText'
```

or as Routing

```
window.location.href = '/users/login/message/yourMessageText'
```

?