# Rails Redirect_to not rendering the view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to load a view after some actions in my controller, I'm getting the message that the view was loaded, but the view is never showed

My Controller:

```
def getBalance
 @result
 accountId = params['accountId']
 baseURLUpdate = 'http://xxxxxxxxxx' + accountId + '/statement'
 transactionHash = generateTransactionHash(accountId)
 @result = HTTParty.get(baseURLUpdate.to_str,
 :headers => { 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
              'Api-Access-Key' => 'xxxxxxxx',
              'Transaction-Hash' => transactionHash } )

 puts @result
 redirect_to accounts_response_path(:result => @result)
 return
end
```

My routes:

```
post 'accounts/getBalance', to: "accounts#getBalance"
get 'accounts/response', to: "accounts#responseShow"
```

My view is called responseShow.html.erb, and I do have a response.html.erb too.

I'm getting this:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/accounts/response.html
Completed 302 Found in 409ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/accounts/response.html" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-01-19 10:36:02 -0200
Processing by AccountsController#response_show as HTML
I'm here
Rendered accounts/response_show.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 18ms (Views: 17.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Comment: remove `return` from action

Comment: your view is rendered as js not html: `Processing by AccountsController#responseShow as JS`

Comment: Show us full controller code please.

Comment: You should be using `snake_case` not `camelCase`. So `get_balance` as opposed to `getBalanace`, and so on.

Comment: Already removed the return and it didn't worked, already put the full controller code.

Comment: Also, you are straying dangerously away from the way Rails works. You should be adding some restful actions, instead of `getResponse.html.erb` and so on. Rails doesn't play well when you step away from its Convention over Configuration pattern. You lose a lot of benefits.

Comment: But whats the right way to do it? I just want to display the result in another view

Comment: Are you calling the method getBalance via AJAX ?

Comment: The method is called by AJAX and you want to redirect to view by HTML?

Comment: No, I'm requesting something using HTTP, and I want to show the result of this in another view. Like this : Request from index.html.erb view, and show the result in response.html.erb

Comment: Can you try with 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' ?

Comment: Not working yet @Ruk

Comment: You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call
You sample code says you are redirecting as JS, it should be html not JS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with format block in your controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
 format.html {redirect_to accounts_response_path(:result => @result)}
 format.js   {render :js => "window.location.href='"+accounts_response_path(:result => @result)+"'"}
end
```