# Redirect_to doesn't work with if condition?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following action buy into my controller, in my others actions redirect_to work properly but not here may be it's because the if statements or may be because the flash code ??

```
def buy

cart = params[:cart]
visitor = params[:visitor]

 if cart

   if visitor

    flash[:visitor] = "Please log in or sign up"

   else

    Cart.create(order: cart)
    flash[:confirm] = "Order confirmed"

  end

 else

   flash[:cart_empty!] = "The cart is empty"

 end


redirect_to "/"


end
```

EDIT 1

It seems that the redirection is correctly performed (server log)

```
Redirect to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 2185ms (ActiveRecord: 8.9ms | Allocation: 27088)
```

but the view remain the same ??

*routes.rb*

```
post 'buy', to: 'cart#buy'
```

Comment: Do you see any errors in console logs?

Comment: @SampatBadhe Thank you for your advice I don't see any errors but I see that the redirection seems correctly performed " Redirected to http://localhost:3000/" but the page is still the same...

Comment: Are you sending Ajax request for buy action?

Comment: @SampatBadhe No just html

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console logs?

Comment: @SampatBadhe Nothing wrong in the browser console

Comment: @SampatBadhe I'm sorry effectively the request from the client (navigator) is sent in ajax (with axios)

Comment: This seems to be similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34875255/rails-redirect-to-not-rendering-the-view

Comment: @SampatBadhe Yes thank you the problem is solved :)

Answer (score -1):

There is an error on the second else, an extra exclamation mark:

```rb
flash[:cart_empty!] = "The cart is empty"
```

Remove the exclamation mark and it should work properly:

```rb
flash[:cart_empty] = "The cart is empty"
```