# Redirect_to claims to work, but doesn't actually happen in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redirect, http-status-code-302

Here is the Controller code where I call the redirect:

```
def helpful
  flash[:notice] = I18n.t(:thanks_for_feedback)
  redirect_to :back
end
```

The log claims:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/p/anime/2?page=1
Completed 302 Found in 3147.7ms (Searchkick: 857.1ms)
```

But, nothing actually happens in the browser (Chrome, if it matters).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you're using an AJAX request.

If it is the case, take a look: [Rails 3: How to "redirect_to" in Ajax call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5454806/rails-3-how-to-redirect-to-in-ajax-call)