# Redirecting after ajax request

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I've been reading a lot of posts about how Rails handles `remote: true`, but I still fail to understand why this is happening. One of my form is a remote form, which looks like this:

```
<%= form_with model: @transfer, scope: :transfer, url: transfers_path, method: 'post', remote: true do |f| %>
```

And in my `create` action, I just have this:

```
def create
  @transfer = @account.transfers.build(transfer_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @transfer.valid?
      format.html { redirect_to pending_transactions_path }
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "An error occurred"
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

The `create.js.erb` template is strictly used to handle when there's an error saving the `@transfer` and I also tried to empty it out with no code. And for some reason, when I submit this form, it did redirected me to to the `pending_transactions_path`.

However, in another part of my code, I have an ajax request like this:

```
$.ajax({
  method: "GET",
  url: "/handle_timeout"
});
```

And my controller action looks like this:

```
def handle_timeout
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to pending_transactions_path }
  end
end
```

And it's not redirecting for some reason. In my Rails log, I can see that it's redirecting:

```
10:19:18 web.1     | Redirected to http://localhost:3000/transactions/pending
10:19:18 web.1     | Completed 302 Found in 67ms (ActiveRecord: 50.6ms)
10:19:18 web.1     | Started GET "/transactions/pending" for ::1 at 2019-05-31 10:19:18 -0700
10:19:18 web.1     | Processing by TransactionsController#pending_transfers as */*
```

I had to follow another SO answer to get it to redirect. Link to that answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17689223/3504731

Am I wrong to think `remote: true` is the same as making an `$.ajax` request? Why does my page redirect when I submit the first form, but doesn't redirect when the second ajax request is ran? Does Rails' `remote: true` do more magic under the hood versus an ajax request?

I am running Rails 5.2.1. Any insights on this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for reading!

Comment: Executing a 302 redirect in an AJAX endpoint doesn't smell right to me. In the link you site, the endpoint is sending back some JS that the client will execute to redirect the user. It might help you better organize your code and separate client and server concerns if you limited your AJAX endpoint to only returning JSON. Then using a jQuery callback like [done](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/), you can deliberately code the behavior you want based on the response. This can include a triggering a redirect. I suspect this exercise will reveal deeper concerns with your approach here.

Comment: Hmm that is a good point you pointed out. The only reason I was trying to redirect in an AJAX endpoint is because I have to handle errors inside an `js.erb` template (like notifying Bugsnag, setting flash error, etc.). I couldn't figure out any other way to do this unless I make an AJAX request inside the `js.erb` template, and the action would do a redirect with a flash message to let the user know something went wrong. I also found out that `rails-ujs` adds some magic to Rails `remote: true` so that might be the answer to my question. I'm not sure though.

Comment: I should also add the reason I suspect it's `rails-ujs` is because I noticed the `TransfersController#create` action was returning a 200 status, instead of a 302. So I think instead of a real redirect like what I attempted to do, Rails is handling it a little different when I attempt to submit a `remote: true` form.